# Javascript Form Validation. how to remove error when focused on a input field using onfocus

Tags: javascript, html, css

*Kind of hard for me to explain but here is my attempt to...(FYI I am a Noob so take it easy please)

currently when you submit the form any field that is left black receives an error message. The field also turns red with a red border showing the user that they forgot to put data in the box. Also the label turns from black to red.

What i need is for when the user focuses on a box(using onfocus) the code will change the color of the field label back to regular black and remove the red box around the field indicting that the user has corrected the error.

index.htm:

```
<form name="myForm">

        <legend>Customer Information</legend>

    <fieldset id="custInfo">

        <article id="errorFName"></article>
        <article id="errorLName"></article>
        <article id="errorAddress"></article>
        <article id="errorCity"></article>
        <article id="errorState"></article>
        <article id="errorZip"></article>
        <article id="errorUsername"></article>
        <article id="errorPassword"></article>
        <article id="errorAgreement"></article>
        <article id="passwordMatchMessage"></article>


        <label id="firstNameLabel" for="firstName">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" />


        <label type="text" for="middleInitial">Middle Initial:</label>
        <input name="middleInitial" id="middleInitial" size="2" />

        <label id="lastNameLabel" for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" 
               placeholder="Last Name"/>


        <label id="streetAddressLabel" for="streetAddress">Street Address:</label>
        <input name="streetAddress" id="streetAddress" />


        <label id="cityLabel" for="city">City:</label>
        <input type="text" name="city" id="city" placeholder="Tulsa"/>


        <label id="stateLabel" for="state">State:</label>
        <input type="text" name="state" id="state" placeholder="OK"/>


        <label id="zipLabel" for="zip">Zip Code:</label>
        <input name="zip" id="zip" 
               placeholder="xxxxx (-xxxx)"/>


        <label id="usernameLabel" for="username">Username:</label>
        <input name="username" id="username" 
               placeholder="username"/>


        <label id="passwordLabel" for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" 
               placeholder="password"/>


        <label id="confirmPasswordLabel" for="confirmPassword">Password Confirmation:</label>
        <input type="password" name="confirmPassword" id="confirmPassword" onkeyup="passwordMatch(); return false;"/>


        <label id="userAgreement">
        <input type="checkbox" name="userAgreement" id="userAgreement" />

        By clicking the checkbox, you agree to our Terms and that you have read our <a href="#">Data Use Policy</a>, including our <a href="#">Cookie Use</a>.
        </label>  
        <p>
            <button id="submitButton" onclick="return validateForm();">Submit</button>
            <button id="resetButton">Reset</button>

        </p>

    </fieldset>


    </form>
```

style.css:

```
/* Styles for Fieldset*/

body {
background: #E8E8E8 ;
}

form {
width: 500px;
margin: 50px;
}

fieldset#custInfo {
background-color: #99ccff;
border: 2px solid #0066ff;

}

legend {
background-color: #0066ff;
color: white;
padding: 10px 0px;
text-indent: 10px;
width: 100%;
}



/*Styles for labels*/

label{
clear: left;
display: block;
float: left;
font-size: 0.9em;
margin: 13px 4% 7px 5px;
width: 150px;
}

label#userAgreement {
margin: auto;
width: 100%;
font-size: 0.8em;
}
/*Styles for input*/

input {
display: block;
float: left;
font-size: 0.9em;
height: 25px;
margin: 7px 0px;
width: 250px;

}

input#userAgreement {
width: 15px;
margin: auto 5px;
}

/*style for Buttons*/


button {
display: block;
float: left;
height: 40px;
width: 200px;
margin: 0px 11px;
}



article {
display: block;
font-size: 0.9em;
color: red;
margin: 7px 10px;


}
```

validation.js (I Do apologize for the messy code, I am a noob)

```
function validateForm() {

var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName');
var firstNameLabel = document.getElementById('firstNameLabel')
var lastName = document.getElementById('lastName')
var lastNameLabel = document.getElementById('lastNameLabel')

if( firstName.value == "" )
{
        firstName.style.border = "1px solid red";
        firstName.style.backgroundColor = "#FFCCCC";
        firstNameLabel.style.color = "red";
        errorFName.innerHTML = 'First Name cannot be left blank!';

}



if( document.getElementById('lastName').value == "" )
{
        lastName.style.border = "1px solid red";
        lastName.style.backgroundColor = "#FFCCCC";
        lastNameLabel.style.color = "red";
        errorLName.innerHTML = 'Last Name cannot be left blank!';

}

if( document.getElementById('streetAddress').value == "" )
{
        document.getElementById('streetAddress').style.border = "1px solid red";
        document.getElementById('streetAddress').style.backgroundColor = "#FFCCCC";
        document.getElementById('streetAddressLabel').style.color = "red";
        errorAddress.innerHTML = 'Address cannot be left blank!';

}

if( document.getElementById('city').value == "" )
{
        document.getElementById('city').style.border = "1px solid red";
        document.getElementById('city').style.backgroundColor = "#FFCCCC";
        document.getElementById('cityLabel').style.color = "red";
        errorCity.innerHTML = 'City cannot be left blank!';

}

if( document.getElementById('state').value == "" )
{
        document.getElementById('state').style.border = "1px solid red";
        document.getElementById('state').style.backgroundColor = "#FFCCCC";
        document.getElementById('stateLabel').style.color = "red";
        errorState.innerHTML = 'State cannot be left blank!';

}

if( document.getElementById('zip').value == "" )
{
        document.getElementById('zip').style.border = "1px solid red";
        document.getElementById('zip').style.backgroundColor = "#FFCCCC";
        document.getElementById('zipLabel').style.color = "red";
        errorZip.innerHTML = 'Zip Code cannot be left blank!';

}

if( document.getElementById('username').value == "" )
{
        document.getElementById('username').style.border = "1px solid red";
        document.getElementById('username').style.backgroundColor = "#FFCCCC";
        document.getElementById('usernameLabel').style.color = "red";
        errorUsername.innerHTML = 'Username cannot be left blank!';

}
if( document.getElementById('password').value == "" )
{
        document.getElementById('password').style.border = "1px solid red";
        document.getElementById('password').style.backgroundColor = "#FFCCCC";
        document.getElementById('passwordLabel').style.color = "red";
        errorPassword.innerHTML = 'The Password cannot be left blank!';

}

if( document.myForm.confirmPassword.value == "") 
{
        document.getElementById('confirmPassword').style.border = "1px solid red";
        document.getElementById('confirmPassword').style.backgroundColor = "#FFCCCC";
        document.getElementById('confirmPasswordLabel').style.color = "red";
}

if( document.myForm.userAgreement.checked == false)
{
    document.getElementById('userAgreement').style.color = "red";
    errorAgreement.innerHTML = 'You must agree to our User Agreement by checking the Box!'
}



return false;

}        


function passwordMatch() {
var password = document.getElementById('password');
var confirmPassword = document.getElementById('confirmPassword');
var message = document.getElementById('passwordMatchMessage');


if(password.value == confirmPassword.value){
    myForm.confirmPassword.style.backgroundColor = "#66CC66";
    message.innerHTML = 'Passwords Match!';
}

else {
    myForm.confirmPassword.style.backgroundColor = "#FFCCCC";
    message.innerHTML = 'Passwords Do Not Match!';
}
return false;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input').onfocus=function(){
    this.value='';
    this.style.border='';
    this.style.backgroundColor ='';
}
```

Comment: For **input** elements `this.innerHTML='';` should be `this.value='';`